# graphql throwing 400 error even though the query is valid

Tags: reactjs, next.js, graphql, gql

Following is the error that is being thrown when I am trying to load into the page, I have narrowed down the function that is throwing this error. That function is shown below the error. I am not sure what is causing this as it was working fine a few hours back, I have made changes to the file but not directly to this function.

Also when I visit the website which is the graphQLAPI, when I input the same query I do get an output, so the query is valid.

```
error - ClientError: GraphQL Error (Code: 400): {"response":{"error":"{\"errors\":[{\"message\":\"environment \\\"master;\\\" is invalid\"}],\"data\":null}","status":400,"headers":{}},"request":{"query":"\n    query MyQuery {\n      postsConnection {\n        edges {\n          cursor\n          node {\n            author {\n              bio\n              name\n              id\n              photo {\n                url\n              }\n            }\n            createdAt\n            slug\n            title\n            excerpt\n            featuredImage {\n              url\n            }\n            categories {\n              name\n              slug\n            }\n          }\n        }\n      }\n    }\n  "}}
    at C:\Users\shant\Desktop\React-Projects\project-1\node_modules\graphql-request\dist\index.js:359:31
    at step (C:\Users\shant\Desktop\React-Projects\project-1\node_modules\graphql-request\dist\index.js:63:23)
    at Object.next (C:\Users\shant\Desktop\React-Projects\project-1\node_modules\graphql-request\dist\index.js:44:53)
    at fulfilled (C:\Users\shant\Desktop\React-Projects\project-1\node_modules\graphql-request\dist\index.js:35:58)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5) {
  response: {
    error: '{"errors":[{"message":"environment \\"master;\\" is invalid"}],"data":null}',
    status: 400,
    headers: Headers { [Symbol(map)]: [Object: null prototype] }
  },
  request: {
    query: '\n' +
      '    query MyQuery {\n' +
      '      postsConnection {\n' +
      '        edges {\n' +
      '          cursor\n' +
      '          node {\n' +
      '            author {\n' +
      '              bio\n' +
      '              name\n' +
      '              id\n' +
      '              photo {\n' +
      '                url\n' +
      '              }\n' +
      '            }\n' +
      '            createdAt\n' +
      '            slug\n' +
      '            title\n' +
      '            excerpt\n' +
      '            featuredImage {\n' +
      '              url\n' +
      '            }\n' +
      '            categories {\n' +
      '              name\n' +
      '              slug\n' +
      '            }\n' +
      '          }\n' +
      '        }\n' +
      '      }\n' +
      '    }\n' +
      '  ',
    variables: undefined
  },
  page: '/'
}
```

The function that I believe is throwing this error is

```
export const getPosts = async () => {
  console.log(graphqlAPI)
  const query = gql`
    query MyQuery {
      postsConnection {
        edges {
          cursor
          node {
            author {
              bio
              name
              id
              photo {
                url
              }
            }
            createdAt
            slug
            title
            excerpt
            featuredImage {
              url
            }
            categories {
              name
              slug
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  `;

  const result = await request(graphqlAPI, query);

  return result.postsConnection.edges;
};
```

Comment: Are you setting an environment variable somewhere?

Comment: @ToniBardinaComas yes I do have a .env file

Comment: Which is the value of your environment variable by the time of doing the query?

Comment: @ToniBardinaComas I fixed it, I was accidentally using semicolons in my .env file